# How to ignore packages in netbeans 8

Tags: java, netbeans

I inherited a big project, of which only a few packages are relevant to my work.  I accidentally edited the wrong package today, and to avoid this in the future, would like to exclude them from netbean's project viewer (but not change them on disk).

Looks like there was an `ignored folders` property in older versions of netbeans (https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/ignored_folders_sure) but I can't find this anywhere in netbeans8.1.  Does it still exist?

Comment: The blog you've linked to seems to be dealing with PHP, not Java

Comment: In the project properties, under the "Sources" option, there is an "Includes/Excludes" button, I'm not if this will do what you want though

Comment: I'm kind of confused by "edited the wrong package".  Was it the case that the class, interface, or enum you were meant to revise has the same name in two different packages?

Comment: Sort of.  I'm collaborating on a project, and some packages are named FOO and some are name FOO2, for example.  I edited FOO when I meant to edit FOO2, so i want to hide FOO2 from the editor explicitly

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans does not actually let you hide any packages that you have opened as a part of your project. One thing you can do is to select a package you do not want and choose to close it instead. After closing, you can "delete" it from your perspective. A dialogue will pop up and what you DO NOT want to do is also delete project contents on the disk, so be sure to unselect that option. :)

Comment: Thanks.  But how do you "close" it?  I only see Delete, and when I choose it, it removes the package from disk... no option otherwise

Comment: That doesn't sound right. There should be a dialogue that pops up...hm. Try loading up a temp project and pressing delete(like the keyboard key) when you select a package. I could have sworn that it asks you to confirm..One thing to note is that you might need to add some class file into the package to test it out so that there is something on the disk.

Comment: I think that screen pops up when you delete and entire project.  The package delete screen only gives you the option to "Safely delete (with usage search).  I'll see if I can hide the folders in my SVN instead...